# Connection between peers never happen on custom blockchain

Tags: mining, private-blockchain

My app connects and mine the same blokchain on every instance, it uses the same genesis.json and network ids.

Genesis: https://github.com/AugustoL/OpenContent/blob/master/genesis.json

Web3 service that connects using the same network id: https://github.com/AugustoL/OpenContent/blob/master/js/services/web3.js

When I run it on two different computers the existent blockchain isnt recognized. SO it starts mining two different blockchains with the same genesis and network id :S

What is the error? What im missing? I have been reading a lot and its supposed to work.

Comment: which command do you start on the CLI?

Comment: Something like: geth --networkid "1998165215114019841" --genesis ./genesis.json --datadir ./blockchain --rpc --verbosity=4 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain="http://localhost:80" --rpcapi "admin,eth,miner,net,personal,web3" --nat "any" --extradata "OpenContent 0.1"

You can view it here: https://github.com/AugustoL/OpenContent/blob/master/js/services/web3.js

Comment: ah ok, just wanted to be sure that `--nodiscover` is not set. Hmm, I suspect you read also the chapter about "setting up multiple node"  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster and the part about "common problems with connectivity"  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network ?

Comment: Yes I already read it and try addinng the nodes manually but it didnt work :S

Comment: Please make sure you don't have a firewall blocking UDP/TCP connections on port `30303`.

Comment: @PéterSzilágyi , they are not blocked.

Answer (score 5):

## The Reason

The reason why your two `geth` instances on the two different computers cannot find each other is that they do not know where to start searching for each other.

Note: I've shortened the node public key for easier reading in this answer. For example,
`"a979fb575495b8d6db44f750317d0f4622bf4c2aa3365d6af7c284339968eef29b69ad0dce72a4d8db5ebb4968de0e3bec910127f134779fbcb0cb6d3331163c"` has been shortened to `"a979....163c"`. You will have to use the full public keys when setting up your network.

In the mainnet public blockchain, each peer upon starting up will try to connect to the "bootnodes" to obtain an initial list of peers it can connect to. The address of these bootnodes are hardcoded into [eth/backend.go lines 71-78](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/backend.go#L71-L78) as shown below:

```
defaultBootNodes = []*discover.Node{
    // ETH/DEV Go Bootnodes
    discover.MustParseNode("enode://a979....163c@52.16.188.185:30303"), // IE
    discover.MustParseNode("enode://de47....c786@54.94.239.50:30303"),  // BR
    discover.MustParseNode("enode://1118....5082@52.74.57.123:30303"),  // SG
    // ETH/DEV cpp-ethereum (poc-9.ethdev.com)
    discover.MustParseNode("enode://979b....37f9@5.1.83.226:30303"),
}
```

Once a node connects to the bootnode, it will get a list of addresses for potential peers to connect to, and it will try to connect to these peers.

There is no such starting point in your private network.

---

## The Solution

On your private network, your `geth` instances will not know where to start searching for each other and you will have to give it some hints. There are three ways you can do this - using the `--bootnodes` command line parameter, adding a `static-nodes.json` to your data directory, or adding a `trusted-nodes.json` to your data directory.

Run `geth` on each of your computers, and type `admin.nodeInfo` into the command line:

```
> admin.nodeInfo
{
  enode: "enode://d9d9....30d9@[::]:30301?discport=0",
  id: "d9d9....30d9",
  ip: "::",
  listenAddr: "[::]:30301",
  name: "Geth/v1.3.6/linux/go1.5.1",
  ports: {
    discovery: 0,
    listener: 30301
  },
  ...
}
```

What you will have to do is to get the enode information for both your computers. Replace the `[::]` in the enode information with the IP address of your two computers and remove the `?discport=0` if it is present. Your enode information for each computer should then look like:

- Computer 1 enode: `enode://d9d9....30d9@192.168.1.152:30303`
- Computer 2 enode: `enode://1212....3434@192.168.1.253:30303`

### Solution 1 - The `--bootnodes` Solution

This first `--bootnodes` solution will require you to specify the bootnode of one computer's `geth` instance to the other computer's `geth` instance. So on Computer 1, you start up `geth` adding the following parameter:

```
--bootnodes "enode://1212....3434@192.168.1.253:30303"
```

### Solution 2 - The `static-nodes.json` Solution

This second solution is to create the file `static-nodes.json` in your `--datadir`, so in your case, the file name and path should be `./blockchain/static-nodes.json`. On computer #1, this file should contain the enode information of computer #2, and vice versa. Alternatively, just create one `static-nodes.json` with the enode information of both computers #1 and #2, and copy this `static-nodes.json` to the `--datadir` of both computers. The contents of this file should look like:

```
[
  "enode://d9d9....30d9@192.168.1.152:30303",
  "enode://1212....3434@192.168.1.253:30303"
]
```

### Solution 3 - The `trusted-nodes.json` Solution

Same as solution #2, but use the file name `trusted-nodes.json` instead of `static-nodes.json`. The difference here is that trusted nodes don't add to count of peer nodes when the `--maxpeers` limit is reached.

---

### Use `--maxpeers` And Don't Use `--nodiscover`

You may have to specify a non-zero `--maxpeers` to get this working, for example, use the parameter:

```
geth ... --maxpeers 2 ...
```

And don't use `--nodiscover` in your `geth` command line, as this will turn off peer discovery.

---

## Related Questions

Here are some related questions that may help you resolve your connection issues:

- [Peer discovery not working on private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/peer-discovery-not-working-on-private-network)
- [Losing connection between nodes on private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2727/losing-connection-between-nodes-on-private-network)

Comment: Nicely explained

Comment: You should consider closing the question as `duplicate` when you find similarity, there is no point in answering a question which is already answered. And the other question is answered by you as well +1 for that.

Comment: This answer is clearer as I now understand the issues a bit better than when I answered the previous question. Should I mark the previous two questions as duplicates of this one?

Comment: Not necessary, i have marked this as duplicate, it will get closed soon. Btw, you're doing a great job here mate. 2K+ reps in 2 week; impressive.

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing my research on the Ethereum blockchain and smart contracts, and the questions that gets asked here helps me to explore the ecosystem. I'm documenting some of these issues so I can reference it in the future. And this blockchain is like Lego Mindstorm to me, compared to regular programming being regular Lego. Lots of pieces to explore and see how they fit together.

Comment: Too much enthusiasm :) you can be next John Skeet here.

Comment: This is my procrastination mechanism. I'm meant to be doing a whole lot of other things that I don't want to do, so I'm just losing myself in my hobbies.