# Running a custom private go-ethereum node cluster using docker

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, docker

Here is a set up I have been working on and am having issues with ability to create a private network with peers. 
Basic set up: Used the dockerfile from https://github.com/ethereum/ethereum-dockers/tree/master/go-ethereum-base, and added a line for installation of Ethereum to the image.

1. Upon creation of the image, I ran 2 instances of the image, (note that both contain basic custom genesis JSON file)

   ```
   docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:30303:30303 -p 3001:3001 --name e1
   ```

   and

   ```
   docker run -it -p 127.0.0.1:30304:30304 -p 3002:3002 --name e2 \
     --link e1:e1
   ```
2. Next, I attached to the container, e1 and ran the following command:

   ```
   geth --identity "ethnode1" --datadir "/tempdatadir1" --rpc         \
     --port "30303" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcport "3001"              \
     --genesis genesis.json --networkid 6161                          \
     --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" \
     --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --nat "any" --maxpeers 2 console
   ```

This launched a `geth` console, wherein I am able to check the node info using commands such as `admin.nodeInfo`, etc. Extracted the enode value for connecting the second node: `enode://@[::]:30303`

Exit console using Crtl-C

3. Attached to the container e2, and ran the following command:

   ```
   geth --identity "ethnode2" --datadir "/tempdatadir2" --rpc         \
     --port "30304" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcport "3002"              \
     --genesis genesis.json --networkid 6161                          \
     --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" \
     --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --nat "any" --maxpeers 2 console
   ```

This launched a `geth` console, wherein I am able to check the node info using commands such as `admin.nodeInfo`, etc. At this point, I tried adding the first node using the following command: `admin.addPeer("enode://@127.0.0.1:30303")`, which returns true. 
However, when I try to list the peers using either `admin.Peers`, I see an empty array and using `net.peerCount` gives 0.

Suggestions, as to how the connectivity between the two can be enabled?

- Is it that the wrong IP address is being used? In general, is it possible to utilize a specific IP address from the host by forwarding the IP Address appropriately.
- Should the console not be exited in Step 2 above?
- In either of the above cases, how do we connect to an existing `geth` instance? I tried using `geth attach "http://127.0.0.1:3001"`, but it gave me an error saying, connection refused. Any suggestions as to how we can attach to an existing `geth` instance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Summary

1. Check that there is network connectivity between the two Docker containers and reconfigure if necessary. Check there is sufficient memory allocated to each container.
2. In each Docker container

   - Install the go-ethereum `geth` program
   - Create two accounts (Ethereum addresses)
   - Run `geth` with the exact same custom `genesis.json` file, same `--networkid`, `--datadir` set to your preferred directory and with the parameter for `geth` to start mining.
   - Test that `geth` is working
3. Connect the `geth` instances.

**Short Answer To Your Questions**

- Q: How the connectivity between the two can be enabled?

  - A: First set up connectivity between the Docker containers. Some references provided, but don't use `127.0.0.1` as this is normally confined to be used within your operating system / Docker container.
- Q: Is it that the wrong IP address is being used? In general, is it possible to utilize a specific IP address from the host by forwarding the IP Address appropriately.

  - A: There should be a non-`127.0.0.1` IP address available from within the Docker container. Instructions below to find this address.
- Q: Should the console not be exited in Step 2 above?

  - A: Test your setup first using `geth ... console`. Don't exit the `geth` command prompt while you are testing.
- Q: In either of the above cases, how do we connect to an existing geth instance? I tried using geth attach "http://127.0.0.1:3001", but it gave me an error saying, connection refused. Any suggestions as to how we can attach to an existing geth instance?

  - A: I've listed some tests below to check your Docker container networking connectivity. Once connectivity is resolved, use your `--rpc*` parameters and your should be able to connect using `geth attach ...` with the non-`127.0.0.1` address and port.

---

**EDIT 23/04/2016** - OP solved the connectivity issue using `192.*.*.*` instead of `127.0.0.1` for the IP addresses as shown in the following Docker commands:

```
docker run -it -p 192.XXX.XXX.XXX:30303:30303 --name e1 <eth image>
```

and

```
docker run -it -p 192.XXX.XXX.XXX:30304:30304 --name e2 --link e1:e1 <eth image>
```

**EDIT 24/04/2016** - OP has the data directories to be created in the root (`/`) directory. This will require superuser (root) permission. It is better to store the data directory within your home directory. Use `$HOME/tempdatadir1` instead of `/tempdatadir1`. By default, `geth` will create your data directory in `$HOME/.ethereum`.

## Details Below

---

### Docker Container Connectivity And Requirements

#### Memory

`geth` will require more than 512 Mb so you may want to test with 1 Gb and increase it if necessary.

#### Docker Networking

**Aim**

You will need to set up your Docker containers so that `geth` in Container #1 can connect to `geth` in Container #2 and vice versa.

In your question, you have mapped `127.0.0.1:30303` to be accessed externally through port `30303`. The `127.0.0.1` IP address is a  **localhost** addresses that normally does not allow communication from outside the operating system. Please check for the non-`127.0.0.1` IP address by using `ifconfig -a` within your Docker containers to determine what your non-localhost IP addresses are. Try using these IP addresses to communicate across the Docker containers.

**References**

- [Docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)
- [Docker network features](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/)
- [Connecting Docker Containers, Part Two](https://deis.com/blog/2016/connecting-docker-containers-2/)

**Check Connectivity**

Get the IP address from within Container #1 using `ifconfig -a`:

```
ifconfig -a
lo      ...
        inet addr:127.0.0.1 ...
        ...
docker0 ...
        inet addr:192.168.0.1
```

Run `geth` on port 30303 in Container #1 as shown in the next section (or as you documented in your Question).

From Container #2 or the host, you should be able to run the following command - you will have to hit Control-C to teminate the connection:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ telnet 192.168.0.1 30303
Trying 192.168.0.1...
Connected to 192.168.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If your IP address is not set up to receive your connection attempt, your results should look like:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ telnet 192.168.0.1 30303
Trying 192.168.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
```

If your IP address is correct, but your port is not mapped correctly, you should see:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ telnet 192.168.0.1 30303
Trying 192.168.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

---

### Configure `geth`

Configure `geth` with the basic parameters so we can verify that it is working as expected, without the P2P connection between the Docker containers. You will firstly need to configure two accounts to test your mining.

**New Accounts**

In Container #1, run the following command twice to create two new accounts:

```
user@Kumquat:~$ geth --datadir "$HOME/tempdatadir1" account new
Your new account is locked with a password. Please give a password. Do not forget this password.
Passphrase: 
Repeat Passphrase: 
Address: {a6847de2447db964ef89644752921c204bf563ab}
```

Data related to your account (in encrypted format) is stored in your `--datadir` directory under the subdirectory `keystore`. Make sure that you **back these files up** (and remember your password) if you are using this account in the main Ethereum network.

```
user@Kumquat:~$ ls -al $HOME/tempdatadir1/keystore
total 12
drwx------ 2 user user 4096 Apr 24 16:11 .
drwx------ 3 user user 4096 Apr 24 16:11 ..
-rw------- 1 user user  491 Apr 24 16:11 UTC--2016-04-24T06-11-04.534736154Z--a6847de2447db964ef89644752921c204bf563ab
```

And the same in Container #2, using the `--datadir` for Container #2.

**Run `geth` Miner**

Run the following command in Container #1, and you should see messages like the ones listed below:

```
geth --datadir "/tempdatadir1" --port "30303" \
  --genesis genesis.json --networkid 6161     \
  --mine --minerthreads 1 console
```

Same for Container #2:

```
geth --datadir "/tempdatadir2" --port "30304" \
  --genesis genesis.json --networkid 6161     \
  --mine --minerthreads 1 console
```

The messages you should be seeing follow:

```
I0422 23:24:07.347255    8218 worker.go:348]   Mined block (#6248 / 11175b1e). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I0422 23:24:07.347868    8218 worker.go:569] commit new work on block 6249 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 521.208µs
I0422 23:24:07.348356    8218 worker.go:569] commit new work on block 6249 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 378.62µs
I0422 23:24:18.248751    8218 worker.go:348]   Mined block (#6249 / 50cdfdeb). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I0422 23:24:18.249306    8218 worker.go:569] commit new work on block 6250 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 470.831µs
```

**Sending An Ether From Account #1 to Account #2**

In each container, run the `sendTransaction` command in the `geth` console. You mining operation should be adding ethers to eth.accounts[0] (first account, also called **coinbase**). This command will send an ether from eth.accounts[0] to eth.accounts[1]:

```
> eth.sendTransaction({from: eth.accounts[0], to: eth.accounts[1], value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})
"0xde465790a8ae4ce1aad3179d071ac49ed447c09199de26ce02327e8790e63e4b"
```

Wait for the transaction to be mined. Then run the `getTransaction` command to check the transaction has been mined into a block:

```
> eth.getTransaction("0xde465790a8ae4ce1aad3179d071ac49ed447c09199de26ce02327e8790e63e4b")
{
  ...
  blockNumber: 6266,
  ...
}
```

Check the account balance of `eth.accounts[1]`:

```
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1]), "ether")
1
```

---

### Connect The `geth` Instances

You will need to find the **enode** information for each `geth` instance. I've shortened the long node public key from "d9d93b749257a1d4eaec18ab1c1ad39dc9220e449cfe248aceafc586193ead0ac14a088be5afb8455bd8f14bab7428162b8fbeda399ec748f5df0369789730d9" to "d9d9...30d9" for ease of reading - use the full version in your configuration.

In Container #1, run the following command in the `geth ... console`:

```
> admin.nodeInfo
{
  enode: "enode://d9d9...30d9@[::]:30303?discport=0",
  ...
}
```

Get the same information from `geth` in Container #2.

In the Peer Discovery section below, replace **[::]** in your enode with the externally accessible IP address of your Docker container, and remove the `?discport=0` text.

**Peer Discovery**

You have 3 methods to get `geth` in your Docker containers to connect to each other:

1. Bootnodes

   In Container #1, add the `--bootnodes` parameter to your `geth` command line like, where "d9d9...30d9" needs to be replaced by the appropriate public key for `geth` in Container #2:

   ```
   geth --bootnodes "enode://1234...5678@192.168.0.2:30304" ...
   ```

   In Container #2, you can add the similar parameters:

   ```
   geth --bootnodes "enode://d9d9...30d9@192.168.0.1:30303" ...
   ```

   This will connect your `geth` nodes for the initial peer discovery where they should discover each other an maintain a P2P connection.
2. `static-nodes.json`

   Add the following text, replaced with your node information, in your `--datadir` directory in a file named `static-nodes.json`:

   ```
   [
     "enode://1234...5678@192.168.0.2:30304",
     "enode://d9d9...30d9@192.168.0.1:30303"
   ]
   ```
3. `trusted-nodes.json`

   Same as `static-nodes.json` above, but the node connections here do not count towards the `--maxpeers` parameter if specified.

Try the different configuration styles until I find one that is stable for at least a few days.

**Peer Discovery References**

- [Connection between peers never happen on custom blockchain](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/connection-between-peers-never-happen-on-custom-blockchain/3122#3122)
- [Peer discovery not working on private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2708/peer-discovery-not-working-on-private-network)
- [Losing connection between nodes on private network](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2727/losing-connection-between-nodes-on-private-network)
- [Connecting to the network](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network)

---

### How To Run `geth` In The Background

To run `geth` as a background process, remove the `console` parameter from your `geth` command and append the `&` symbol that will start the process in the background. As you may want to inspect the messages from `geth`, you should pipe (send) the output from `geth` into a log file.

This is how I do it:

1. Make a subdirectory `logs` in your $HOME directory:

   ```
   mkdir $HOME/logs
   ```
2. Set up a script file with your `geth` command line option. I call mine `runGeth` and save it in `$HOME/bin` . Ths full filename is `$HOME/bin/runGeth`, and this file contains:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   # Kill any running geth instances gracefully
   killall -q --signal SIGINT geth

   # Wait for 10 seconds
   sleep 10

   # Make sure that geth is really killed. Try hard killing again
   killall -q geth

   # Run geth in the background,
   #  piping the output messages to a log file
   geth --rpc [other parameters] --verbosity 3 2>> $HOME/logs/geth.log &
   ```

   You will have to run the following command to make this script executable:

   ```
   user@Kumquat:~$ chmod 700 $HOME/bin/runGeth
   ```

   You can now start `geth` running the script from your command line:

   ```
   user@Kumquat:~$ runGeth
   ```

   If this does not work, use the full pathname:

   ```
   user@Kumquat:~$ $HOME/bin/runGeth
   ```
3. To attach to your `geth` instance running in the background, use the command:

   ```
   geth attach
   ```

   This will use the IPC protocol to connect to the `geth` instance running in the background.

   If you want to connect to the `geth` instance from your other Docker container, or from outside your Docker container, use the following command with the correct IP and port numbers:

   ```
   geth attach rpc:http://192.XXX.XXX.XXX:8545
   ```

   Note that the port `8545` is the default RPC port that can be set using the `--rpcport {port}` command line parameter.

   You can exit from these `geth attach` processes without affecting the `geth` instance running in the background.

   And as I don't like typing out long command line parameters, I create the file `$HOME/bin/attachGeth` with the following contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   geth attach rpc:http://192.XXX.XXX.XXX:8545
   ```

   And `chmod 700 $HOME/bin/attachGeth` so I can attach to the background running `geth` using the command `attachGeth` or `$HOME/bin/attachGeth`.
4. To view the log files from the `geth` instance running in the background:

   ```
   tail -F $HOME/logs/geth.log
   ```

   Hit Control-C to terminate this process.

Comment: I've completed re-writing the answer. Hopefully it is clearer. Main issue is getting the connectivity across the Docker containers. Non-127.0.0.1 addresses would work best.

Comment: Extension to the above case: Creating accounts in separate containers and sending funds from one to another container. Few issues with creating accounts at the two separate instances, say g1 and g2 running in their own containers, say e1 and e2. Within e1, I am able to create two accounts using: geth --datadir "d1" account new
1. When a similar command was typed in e2, to create account, after typing in the pass phrase, the error response is "Killed". Note: datadir not created
2. At this point a similar error occurs upon new account creation in e1.
Any suggestions as to how to get around this?

Comment: You normally cannot create a data directory under the root directory, eg: "/tempdatadir1" without the superuser (root) permission. Create your data directory in your home subdirectory using `--datadir $HOME/tempdatadir1` .

Comment: I've just added some instructions to run `geth` in the background to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: This answer could be a blog.. Well written ..

Comment: Quick check: One of the things to ensure is the genesis file is exactly the same at either of the nodes. When pre-allocating funds to a certain account, a step is to say assign 10 units to the account created within a container. A way to do this is by modifying the genesis file and rerunning a geth instance. But at this point, the genesis file becomes different at either node. Questions:
1. If the genesis files are different, would it affect the connectivity between nodes?
2. What would be suggested to allocate funds to accounts created at the nodes and transact from one node to another?

Comment: https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html has a section on the genesis file and initial allocation of funds. It must be the same.

Comment: Got it! The reason I ask the above question(s) is if both nodes have the same genesis.json, then peer discovery works. I am able to list the peers and notice admin.peers having the node at the other container, after running admin.addPeer() at both the containers. However, upon allocating separate accounts by populating the "alloc" object in the genesis.json, admin.addPeer() returns true at both containers, but neither net.peerCount nor admin.peers return any results showing the peer that was added on each of the containers.

Comment: Is it important for you to have the pre-mined coins allocated to both accounts? If it is, https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp/wiki/Custom-genesis has an example of how to allocate pre-mined coins to more than one account - use the same genesis.json on each node. If it is not, your accounts will be populated with 5 ethers for each block that the nodes mine anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Eris has a geth Dockerfile with some custom scripts here:

https://github.com/eris-ltd/common/tree/master/docker/geth

It's somewhat out of date though updates are in the pipeline over the next month. The image for that Dockerfile is `quay.io/eris/geth` and can be run with `eris services start geth` if [eris-cli](https://github.com/eris-ltd/eris-cli) is installed.

Subscribe to [this issue](https://github.com/eris-ltd/eris-cli/issues/692) to track progress.